# MySQL REPLACE(a, b) equivalent in mongodb?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm trying to replace a pattern in mongodb. In MySQL I just do

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, ?, ?)
```

What about mongodb? I need to work on a collection with 200K records, looping through the collection and write back is a bad idea. I need a builtin function to do that.

Tried to google for `REPLACE` method, but didn't find anything releated

Comment: AFAIK looping through the entire collection is your only option, assuming you can't restrict the target documents using some criteria.

Comment: can you share collection data at https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar It's just one string field to replace

Comment: Please use this coed db.collection('demo').find( { notes: { $regex: "/school/" }}).toArray((err, docs) => {
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    let notes = doc.notes.replace('school', 'college');
    db.collection('demo').updateOne({_id: doc._id}, {notes});
  });
});

Comment: I believe it is possible without using looping at the application side. You have to use aggregations and $contact or $regex and $set .  But have to play around it to find out exact query.